# C#: How do i modify this code to split the string with hyphens?

Tags: c#, string, split

Hello i need some help modifying this code so it splits this string with hyphens:

```
string KeyString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
```

I would like to lay it out like this:

1234-1234-1234-1234

with a char length of 4 per segment and max chars about 16

Full Code

```
     private static string GetKey()
    {
        char[] chars = new char[62];
        string KeyString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        chars = KeyString.ToCharArray();

        RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] data = new byte[1];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        data = new byte[8];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(8);

        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length - 1)]);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

the code is used for generating random ids

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry but I'm at total loss here. You say one thing and post code doing something that is absolutely not related. What does split or Console input have to do with that code? What do you want to split? As a side note, the code can be greatly optimized, but that's another matter.

Comment: Do you understand that the code to generate some random id's is totally irrelevant to the code used to split a string?

Comment: sorry im new to this thing i need to split String KeyString into 4 different segments of ids into the c# console

Comment: so its like EXAMPLE: 1234-1234-1234-1234 seperated by hyphens

Comment: poorly phrased but useful question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && (i % 4) == 0)
        result.Append("-");

    result.Append(chars[data[i] % (chars.Length - 1)]);
}
result.Length -= 1; // Remove trailing '-'
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't... resist... regex... solution

```
string KeyString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

Console.WriteLine(
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(".{4}")
    .Replace(KeyString, "$&-").TrimEnd('-'));
```

outputs

```
abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-qrst-uvwx-yzAB-CDEF-GHIJ-KLMN-OPQR-STUV-WXYZ-1234-5678-90
```

But yes, if this is a Guid, by all means, use that type.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to have a look into [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey1zx63.aspx), it produces strings in the format xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx (32 chars) if you definitely want 16 chars, you could take some  16 chars in the middle of the 32 generated by Guid.

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid(); /* f.e.: 0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e */
string randomid = guid.ToString().Substring(4, 19);
```